# How to query a relationship that spans three models in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=166)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    

class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=166)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station)


class Workout(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
```

I then created a table that presents the exercises for each workout using the following view:

```
def planodet(request, id):
    plan = Workout.objects.get(id=id)
    exercises = plan.exercises.values()
```

But when I loop through `exercises` I can't fetch the Station name. How can I access this?

I've tried

```
Station.objects.filter(name=exercises[0])
```

But to no success.

Comment: @tdy thank you, but it is a typo in here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def planodet(request, id):
    plan = Workout.objects.get(id=id)
    exercises = plan.exercises.values('station__name','reps','series','exercise')
```

just be explicit to get the `station__name`